# Prevent a directory from being pushed in mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs, bitbucket, hgignore

I created a new repository on my local computer, added files and committed giving me the following structure in my working copy:

```
-/a     
-/b
```

I want to push my initial commit to a remote repository on Bitbucket. I however want to ignore directory `b` so that it doesn't get pushed. I added

```
syntax:
glob b/**
```

to my `.hgignore` file. The `b` directory gets pushed anyways.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `.hgignore` add:

```
^b/.*
```

or `b/*` if you are using the inferior `glob` syntax (regex gives you much more control).

The syntax is defined on the first line, and all rules are defined in following seperate lines.

if you want globbing, the first line would be `syntax: glob` and if regex, the first line would be `syntax: regexp` (implied by default). Refer to the [documentation](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html).

Note that mercurial does not actually push empty directories, so the only way you will be able to test it is if you have a file in `b/`

Comment: hgignore not only prevents files from being tracked but also prevents them from being pushed. Is that right?

Comment: @kayfun `.hgignore` acts as a filter for rejecting untracked files (e.g. when doing a plain `hg add` with no arguments). If you have already got files in `b/` being tracked, then it wont automatically *untrack* these files. Check (via `hg st --all`) if there are already files in `/b` being tracked and remove them manually (via `hg forget`) if they are; they might already have been tracked before you created a hgignore.

Answer (score 5):

This cannot be done in Mercurial: you cannot push only an initial version of a file and then ignore later modifications. You can also not push part of a changeset — you either push the entire changeset or not. This way Mercurial makes sure you have a consistent snapshot of your project in all clones.

Preet is correct when he writes that the `.hgignore` file is a filter for **untracked** files. The `.hgignore` file is used to filter the output of commands like `hg status` and to filter the files added by running `hg add` with no further arguments.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just want to be sure I understand you. The b directory referred to in my question is actually a Zend library which is very large, reason I do not want it pushed. So what I should have done initially was create my repository, create my .hgignore file ignoring the zend library directory, add the files to the repository and then commit. That way, the zend directory doesnt get pushed as it is was never added to be tracked by mercurial. Is that correct?

Comment: @kayfun: That is correct — don't track things you don't want to push around.

Comment: Ok, I just did an hg forget on the added files I do not want tracked or pushed. I already made changes to the working copy meaning that a changeset already exists, I just perfomed a forget operation which will be added to the changeset. My first commit was labeled 'Initial Commit', If i commit the current changeset and label it 'changes' and I decide to push to an empty remote repository, i am guessing the 'Initial Commit' will be pushed 1st which will include the Zend directory, the 'changes' will be pushed next causing the remote repository also to forget the zend directory. Is that correct?

Comment: @kayfun: the remote repository will delete the Zend directory when you update and you'll have to recreate the file again afterwards. (Running `hg forget` is just like `hg remove` except that the files are left behind in **your** working copy. The rest of the world sees the operation as a `hg remove`.)

Comment: @kayfun, if 'Initial Commit' was committed with the Zend directory, it will be pushed if you upload to a remote repository.  It is a part of history.  If you haven't pushed *anything* to the remote repository, you may want to delete the .hg folder (the history) and recreate the 'Initial Commit' with Zend properly ignored.